# Why I cant use the column name in the alias when i opered with dates

Tags: sql, apache-spark, date, hive, hiveql

Currently I am migrating a database from SQL_SERVER to SPARK using HIVE_SQL.

I had an issue when im trying to pass a number to a date format.I found the answer is:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(DATE as string) , 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
```

When I execute this query it bring me the data, notice that iI put an alias different to the name of column FECHA :

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(FECHA AS STRING ) ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS FECHA_1
FROM reportes_hechos_avisos_diarios
LIMIT 1

|   FECHA_1    | 
| --------     |
| 2019-01-01   |
```

But when I put the same alias as the column name it bring me an incosistent information:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(FECHA AS STRING ) ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')  AS FECHA
FROM reportes_hechos_avisos_diarios
LIMIT 1

|  FECHA   | 
| -------- |
| 2.019    |
```

I know the trivial answer is , put an alias that doesnt be the same as the column name, but i have an implementation in Tableau that feeds from this query and Its complicated to change this columns because basically i must change all implementation so I need to preserve the column name.This query works for me in SQL SERVER, but i dont know why doesnt works in hive.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc6cE.png)
[ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKX05.png)

PSDT:Thanks for your attention, this is the first question I ask in stack and my native language is not English, sorry if I had grammatical errors.

Comment: The output 2.019 doesn't make any sense to me. Are you sure that's the query you have used?

Comment: Yes thats the query i take a photo.and I put in the original question.

Comment: Can you give an example of the value FECHA takes? Why won't you bring the column FECHA as is and change the data type inside Tableau. Tableau recognizes dates in integer format and this way you don't have to deal with the functions and aliases.

Comment: FECHA takes a number in this format yymmdd->20200101

Comment: https://ibb.co/zn6TcVv There is an example.

Comment: What is the datatype of FETCHA? I guess it is int, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit 1` without `order by` can produce non-deterministic results from run to run because the order of rows is random due to parallel execution, some factors may affect it somehow but getting the same row is not guaranteed.

What is happening - I guess you receiving different row and the date is corrupted in that row, this is why some weird result is returned.

Also, you can another method of conversion:

```
select date(regexp_replace(cast(20200101 as string),'(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})','$1-$2-$3')) --put your column instead of constant.
```

Result:

```
2020-01-01
```

Comment: No I verify  and all the registers are formated correctly, theres no corrupted date , also y do the same exercise whit a normal date and it continous happend.

Comment: @Juanjimenez can you reproduce it with a constant instead of column? Please give me an example of initial DATE